# How to create a "Photo Gallery" in windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'm building one app and I want to make a gallery in my app.

What I did was create a GridView binding all my photos.

But what I really want to do is, create a gallery the same way of Windows Phone.

Comment: Can you post code, any errors, and images referencing what you'd like to achieve?

Comment: [here](http://cmsresources.windowsphone.com/windowsphone/pt-BR/How-to/wp7/block/pictures-concept-hub.png) and when i click it, i can pinch and zoom the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well Microsoft did create a control for this! It's called the MediaViewer Class, but it's a difficult one to use. It's however the closest representation of the actual control used in the WP camera app! It was first featured in the [Basic Lens app sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Basic-Lens-sample-359fda1b) and provided as [a nuget package PhoneMediaViewer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PhoneMediaViewer)

Hope these code examples help